# how can I add my own error messagess and intellisense to a JSON file in visual-studio-code

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I'm building a tool that validates that a JSON file conforms to my custom requirements.

I can let the tool spit out the error messages in the terminal, but I'd rather see these errors be marked in the JSON document itself.

And if possible, I would also like to add code completion for string values in that document.

I have tried to google it, and this link seems promising: [programmatic-language-features](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/programmatic-language-features).
Can you confirm this is the right way forward, or tell me which approach might be more suitable

Comment: It's not clear to me if you're already trying to write an extensions/language-server for vscode, or you just want additional validation for your JSON document.

It sounds as though you are doing what a [json schema][1] already does and VS Code already [has support][2] for those.

Are you trying to do something in addition to what a schema covers?

  [1]: https://json-schema.org/
  [2]: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/json#_json-schemas-and-settings

Comment: @MartinSGill: yes, that is correct. I'm trying to do something in addition to json-schema.

Comment: you may want to look at YAML language server as starting point. Since valid JSON is also valid YAML that might be a good place to investigate. https://github.com/redhat-developer/yaml-language-server

Comment: Thank you, but I'm really looking for a way to program this myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question:
yes: the 'programmatic language features' is one of the 2 ways to do it. The other being: 'language-server-extension'
In my case, I realized that my best option is most likely forking the [JSON-lanugage-server](https://github.com/vscode-langservers/vscode-json-languageserver) and make the necessary changes